# Вызов конструктора наследуемого типа C#

Tags: c#, наследование, конструктор

Здравствуйте. У меня есть вопрос, возможно ли вызвать конструктор объекта, если точно не знаешь какого он типа?
От одного базового класса наследуются несколько других классов. В параметры некой функции я отправляется объект, который наследуется от родителя. В методе есть проверка является ли объект null, если да, то необходимо создать объект. Определять тип объекта я умею, а вот с созданием конструктора у меня проблемы.
Вот пример функции:

```
public static void Open(Form form)
    {
        if (form==null)
        form = new Form();//Вместо этого определить тип(Form1, Form2, и т.д.) 
                          //и вызвать нужный конструктор
        ...
    }
```

Comment: А как вы определяете тип? Что вам мешает создавать объекты нужного вам типа?

Comment: Я сначала хотел совсем по другому решить задачу, в общем определять тип тут даже не нужно, намного легче было использовать универсальные типы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то типа такого?

```
void Main()
{
    OpenForm<Form>();
    OpenForm<Form1>();
    OpenForm<Form2>();
    OpenForm<Form3>();
}

class Form1 : Form { }
class Form2 : Form { }
class Form3 : Form { }

void OpenForm<T>() where T:Form, new()
{       
    var form = new T();
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

Но это только для форм с конструкторами без параметров.

Comment: А чем это будет лучше, чем new Form(), new Form1(), и т.д., если тип известен на этапе компиляции?

Comment: @PrimusSingularis Почему это должно быть лучше, если тип известен? И с чего вы взяли, что он известен? Я то просто ответил на поставленный вопрос, а для чего этот метод нужен автору - спрашивайте у автора